# Select a random customer with an order greater than $1000

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, customer

I've developed a Magento website and I want to select a random customer on a regular basis (for a set period of time) where they have an order greater than $1000 so that we can give them a prize.

How can I find a customer that meets this criteria?

Answer (score 6):

Add grand total filter in order total collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_collection')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','complete')
    ->addFieldToFilter('base_grand_total', array('gteq'=>$grandTotal));

$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is broad question as you'll have to implement some interface in the backend to get that.

But the following code will give you a random customer email that has completed an order.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('customer_email')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','complete');

$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $email = $collection->getFirstItem()->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All answer is right,

But for filter a collection by  **a period then you need** to add `created_at` **at filter of collection by below code**

> ```
> $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
> $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate));
>
> $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
> ```

### Code:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate));

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_collection')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','complete')
    ->addFieldToSelect('customer_email') // get Customer email
    ->addFieldToSelect('customer_firstname') // get Customer first name
   ->addFieldToSelect('customer_lastname')  // get Customer last name
   ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addFieldToFilter('base_grand_total', array('gteq'=>$grandTotal));

$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```